# quasar notify - How to change close button color?

Tags: quasar-framework

I can change text color, button color, icon color, close button text, but NOT the close button color.

[image]

I am using as

```
return Notify.create({
  type: "positive",
  timeout: 0,
  html: true,
  message: "the message",
  closeBtn: true,
  textColor: "white",
});
```

How can i change the color of the 'close' text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Notify's API for `closeBtn` prop:

> Convenient way to add a dismiss button with a specific label, without
> using the 'actions' prop.

In other words, It's a shortcut to automatically add an action button. If you need to customize a button, you should add an action by yourself. Like so:

```js
return Notify.create({
  type: "positive",
  timeout: 0,
  html: true,
  message: "the message",
  textColor: "white",
  actions: [
    { 
      label: 'Close', color: 'white', handler: () => undefined 
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Hi. I'm the creator of Quasar. This is not a workaround. It's how it should actually be done. The `closeBtn` is there for convenience. It's a shortcut to automatically add an action button. If someone needs a customization, he/she should directly add an action instead. It would be stupid to overcomplicate a piece of the API which is a convenience with a duplicated functionality.

Comment: One more thing. The handler can be omitted from the declaration since all action buttons close the notification by default (unless `noDismiss` is set to `true`).

Comment: @RazvanStoenescu: please add a note into documentation, add an example !